# Remove Comma and String Compare in PHP Arrays

Tags: php, string

How to de-concatenate string and verify whether the string is available or not. In my code I am using if string is available from set of comma separated values then check-box will be checked else non checked.

Currently, I am using the following way to do string comparison and verify whether the string is in list or not. Everything is working fine but this method just checks whether string is present in another string or not. In this case I am getting conflict as if "option100" is in values then "option1" "option10" and "option100" are also checked which shouldn't happen.

```
// $fetch_details2['members'] = "option1, option2, option3, option8, option10";
// $fetch_details['username'] = from "option1" to "option10";

    $doquery = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `parents` where school='".$_SESSION['schoolname']."'");
    $doquery2 = mysql_query("SELECT `members` FROM `groups` where groupid='".$_GET['gid']."' AND createdby='".$_SESSION['teauserid']."'");

<?php  while($fetch_details = mysql_fetch_array($doquery)){ ?>
<input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $fetch_details['username']; ?>" <?php if( $fetch_details2['members'],$fetch_details['username']) !== false){ echo "checked"; } ?> />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Please for the safety of you and your users, use prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question properly you can `explode()` the `members` to an array, and then use `in_array()` to determine whether or not to check the corresponding checkbox:

```
$members = array_map('trim', explode(',', $fetch_details2['members']));
<input ... <?php if (in_array($fetch_details['username'], $members)) { echo 'checked'; } ?> />
```